# What does 金山 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, slang

In the following sentence, which is from a comment on [this article](http://slide.news.sina.com.cn/w/slide_1_2841_211969.html#p=1):

> 安倍金山你为什么没有死

It might be an Internet slang, but what does the 金山 mean?

According to many dictionaries for Chinese-English (Pleco, [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E9%87%91%E5%B1%B1), etc), it only lists the meaning as the place names. So I resorted to Chinese-Chinese dictionary, where I found [the following](http://cidian.wenku1.com/%E9%87%91%E5%B1%B1/):

> - 比喻人的仪表英俊、德行崇高。

So, is 金山 a word that includes a derogatory connotation and usually is used to mock a person? I'm sure the Chinese netizen here mocks Abe, and the meaning is something like the following:

> God bless Abe, why have you not died yet, huh?

Is my understanding correct? And also, is 金山 in these cases only used on the Internet or also used in daily life?

Comment: 金山 was a nickname for America, http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/11936/

Comment: Abe just won a resounding victory in the elections. Maybe they just meant '安倍金山 why aren't you politically dead yet?' Although, Baidu gives his name as 安倍晋三. Such transliterations are not always fixed. In your link I don't find 安倍金山。 你打错了吗？

Comment: I assume it's a typo. This kind of typo often happens when you use Pinyin Input.

Comment: It is a typo. `金山` is `jinshan` in pinyin, while `晋三` is `jinsan`.

Comment: @TangHo So is there any relevance between USA and Abe in this context...?

Comment: @Pedroski It is in a comment. You have to unfold it.

Comment: So in this context does 金山 itself have no connotation regarding the derogatory sense (although I'm sure the commentor said it in a negative tone).

Comment: 金山 (United States) is not a derogatory term , It means "the land of rich and plenty"

Comment: @TangHo But do you think the commentor refers to USA in this context? I feel that it is a typo would make more sense.

Comment: 安倍晋三 is Shinzo Abe, one of the most hated name among mainland China because of propagation. 金山 jinshan to 晋三 jinsan is just a typo. 金山 (Mountain of Gold) was a nickname for California - San Francisco specifically - for historical reasons. They are not related.

Comment: @Nathan Just curious - if it is "one of the most", not "the most", who is the most hated person in mainland China?

Comment: @Blaszard When it comes to hatred it's really hard to tell...... I'll say it's among some Chinese ethnic Taiwanese like Ingwen Tsai or Tenghui Lee, or Rebiya Kadeer, or maybe even HH14. It's a country with almost 1.4 B population. You'll easily find 5-6 people hated the most by 200 Mil respectively, lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native speaker here. It could be a typo made unconsciously, or made deliberately to show disrespect to 安倍晋三. Anyway, it's just a typo, with nothing to do with the meaning you found about the word 金山.

By the way, the meaning you found about 金山 is somewhat a Buddhism-related jargon, which is actually rarely used nowadays. For common people 金山 just means "gold mountain" or "rich places with resources".

For example:

> 绿水青山就是**金山银山**。——习近平
>
> Lucid waters and lush mountains are **invaluable assets**. *Xi Jinping*
>
> 其国有**金山**，石皆赤色，其中生金。——《南史》
>
> There's a **gold mountain** in that country, where gold comes from stones that are all red. *History of the Southern Dynasties*

Reference:

http://www.zdic.net/c/1/145/319352.htm
http://www.cctb.net/bygz/zywxsy/201511/t20151113_331161.htm

Comment: Thank you for the added insights and welcome to Chinese Language SE!

Comment: @Blaszard Thank you. I'm happy that my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is a typo.

[Shinzo Abe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinz%C5%8D_Abe)'s name is 安倍晋三. Here they replaced 晋三 (jin4 **san1**) with 金山 (jin1 **shan1**).

Comment: It could also be mocking. Or self-censorship, because, you know, the poster is asking why the person hasn't died. Voluntary or not, you are right, it's probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 character is a name

安倍金山

Prime minister of japan I think

It is better to baidu this name rather than google this name. While there are sarcastic remarks in chinese, this isn't one of them :)

So the comment is just asking why he isn't dead yet. Not really surprising given the countries history but whoever said it probably doesn't mean it in a bad way

Comment: 他叫安倍晋三。金山不是他的名字。

Comment: @Blaszard http://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=0&rsv_idx=1&tn=baidu&wd=%E5%AE%89%E5%80%8D%E9%87%91%E5%B1%B1&rsv_pq=ff60404300005d30&rsv_t=681e0yVwBvYAzzBhmK6Eiw8SGuXyd1BxOLMuHjVnHrrSO95zlr8JOaGkQCk&rqlang=cn&rsv_enter=1&rsv_sug2=0&inputT=8&rsv_sug4=8  it is one of his names that people use

Comment: It got me the results as the related word; not sure how the system works in Baidu but in Google, that works as the system assumes you are mistyping

Comment: Well since baidu is just a google clone, it's probably safe to assume the same. that's just one of the names used for that guy, and given that this sentence came from a comment, on a post on Shinzo Abe, I am confident that whoever typed it just used the wrong characters, possibly due to the typing program he is on where gold mountain was the first choice and people on the internet don't really care about name correctness

Comment: I see. So does it not have the special connotation at all, for example a derogatory connotation?

Comment: I highly doubt it